# Turn Declared String Into An Array

Tags: java, arrays, jgrasp

In my program the user declares a string of numbers that I am trying to figure out to turn into an array. 

Example:

> WeeklyFiber week2 = new WeeklyFiber("CS4567", "11/24/13", 32, "27, 26,
>   28");

Im trying to figure out how to add that string into my class instance variable.
This is what I have:

```
   private String sampleID;
   private String weekOfTest;
   private int engineerID;
   private String[] strengths = new String[20];
   private static int count; 

  public WeeklyFiber(String sampleID, String weekOfTest, int engineerID, String strengths) 
   {
      this.sampleID = sampleID;
      this.weekOfTest = weekOfTest;
      this.engineerID = engineerID;
      this.strengths = strengths;
      count++;
   }
```

My compile error message says incompatible types, required: String[], found: String

Comment: You are trying to assign the string to String[] in the constructor thats why the compiler is giving this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have declared String[] strengths which is an array.

declare your constructor like this :

```
public WeeklyFiber(String sampleID, String weekOfTest, int engineerID, String[] strengths) 
   {
      this.sampleID = sampleID;
      this.weekOfTest = weekOfTest;
      this.engineerID = engineerID;
      this.strengths = strengths;
      count++;
   }
```

Make a call like :

```
WeeklyFiber week2 = new WeeklyFiber("CS4567", "11/24/13", 32, new String[] {"27","26", "28"});
```

Comment: You were right, I needed to change my constructor. Thank you!

Comment: If you think the answer is right please upvote and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it like this:

```
WeeklyFiber week2 = new WeeklyFiber("CS4567", "11/24/13", 32, 
                          new String[] { "27", "26", "28" });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse that `String` of numbers to multiple `String`s. For example,

```
this.strengths = strengths.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't say `this.strengths = strengths` because the `strengths` argument is of type `String` and not `String[]`. That is where your error is coming from.